# Apache load balancing with tomcat : losing session

Tags: apache, load-balancing, tomcat7

I am using proxy pass to load balance my workers. Somehow my tomcat session is getting lost and recreated. I tried standalone tomcat and it works fine but not with load balancer. Please help.

> ```
>   <Proxy *>
>       Order deny,allow
>       Allow from all
>     </Proxy>
>     ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
>     ProxyPass /images !
>     ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/ 
>
>     ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/
>
>     <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
>       BalancerMember ajp://192.168.70.6:9061 route=qa1
>       ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
>     </Proxy>
>     <Location /balancer-manager>
>       SetHandler balancer-manager
>     </Location>
>     <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
>       AllowOverride all   
>     </Directory>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the cause of the issue. I had another server which was being invoked by an absolute URL from the site which was causing the workers JSESSIONID to be overwritten.